# Nginx rewrite for php patch

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

I need to rewrite those url:

```
rewrite /shop.php?category=catergory1 http://example.com/c123 permanent;
rewrite /shop.php?category=category2 http://example.com/c234 permanent;
```

but get "No input file specified" instead of redirecting.

how i should properly write those ?

p.s. i have about one hundred of links like

```
^/shop.php?category=camp&subcategory=&showitem=26
^/shop.php?category=stove&subcategory=&showitem=14
```

and need redirect all of them into 2 different urls - all category=camp to /url1 and all category=stove to /url2
i dont need all of the parameters other than first one in base url.

p.p.s
i should do about 2 thousand permanent redirects for my project. 
could the processing of this redirects be reduce nginx working speed ?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your p.s. this configuration should work for you. Matching the query directly in the rewrite won't work.

```
location /shop.php {
    if ($args ~* "/?category=camp") {
        rewrite ^ http://example.com/url1? permanent;
    }
    if ($args ~* "/?category=stove") {
        rewrite ^ http://example.com/url2? permanent;
    }
}
```

The question mark after "url1" is used to remove the query from the old url.

I'm not quite sure about the performance of that many redirects, however the answers to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/191088/how-many-nginx-redirects-is-too-many) contain some information about that fact.

Comment: ty will read it.
unfortuantly not working. my bad, i thought that it should work with additional parameters.
the real base url is 
`/shop.php?category=camp&subcategory=&showitem=30`
and it not works with the way you proposed.

Comment: For me it works with those parameters too. Could you try a rewrite without the if and then just calling /shop.php?

Comment: i just made rewrite for whole shop.php without parameters.
anyway ty for help